# Changing the var value with apps script fails

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, var

I have a script to create contacts in my database from the contents of my `Google Sheet`. It first verifies the contact doesn't exist in my database, then adds the contact. I have thousands of contacts, so to reduce the number of contacts in the existing contacts cache, I filter my contact list by state.

```
var leadsCache = [];
function createContact(leads){
  var leadState = '';
  for(var i=0; i<leads.length; i++){
    if(leads[i].state != leadState){
      leadState = leads[i].state;
      populateLeadsCache(leadState);
    }
    var existingLead = leadsCache[leads[i].email];
    if(existingLead === undefined){
      var leadId = createNewLead(leads[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

This works as expected, until I get to a lead with a new state. The code hangs here:

```
leadState = leads[i].state;
```

I don't get an error message. I can set the `var` to empty like this: `leadState = ''`, but I cannot set the value to something else.

In stepping through the code, I can see that `leads[i].state` has a new string value.

Why can't I change the value? What is the best way to accomplish my desired results?

**UPDATE**

I wish there was a better error reporting system for `Apps Script`. Turns out I had an issue in `populateLeadsCache` (continuous loop) but the system appeared stuck on `leadState = leads[i].state;`.

Anyone know how to improve the error reporting in `Apps Script`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering the question so it can be closed, but leaving the question here in case someone else has a similar issue that isn't really the issue.

`Apps Script` does not have robust error reporting tools and the debugger failed to highlight the true issue in another part of the code.

When getting a timeout message in `Apps Script` be aware that it may not have anything to do with where the code appears to break.

For me, the next line of code `populateLeadsCache` had an issue if the selected state had too many contacts, which resulted in a continuous loop.